# How to load only metadata in data catalog table using aws crawler

Tags: aws-glue, glue-crawler

I have created AWS crawler to read data from s3 (csv) and have given output config as catalog table. when I ran the crawler I can see both data and metadata populated in catalog table from the csv file.

Is there any way to populate only metadata info into catalog table ? please advise as I am new to AWS world

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AWS Glue Data Catalog **does not** hold any data in the catalog table. It is a [persistent technical metadata store](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/start-data-catalog.html) that describes your data.

That means that when you crawl the data and the table is created in the Data Catalog, it describes the crawled data (showing column data types, location, data format, compression type (if any), partition keys, etc.)

The information you see in those tables **is** the metadata of the crawled table. To access the data that has been crawled, [you can use Athena](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/glue-athena.html) which uses Glue Data Catalog to store and retrieve table metadata for the Amazon S3 data.